# Open Multiple Jquery UI Dialog Boxes. Each with different Content

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have honestly been working on this for about two weeks and researched as much as possible. All I'm attempting to do is have various images on the side of a website. When you click one a dialog box appears with content in it. I can get one dialog to work, but the second wont open a dialog box. I've tried using the .dialog('open') command, but it doesn't seem to accomplish the goal. Here's the code I have so far, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<BODY>

<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"> 
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<A id=infopic href="#"><IMG style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 210px; LEFT: 211px" border=0 src="iconplace.png"></A> 

<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=info>info</DIV>

    <SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

  $("#infopic").click(function() {

        $("#info").dialog({
            autoOpen:"false", 
            stack:"true",
            height: "600",
            width: "700",
            resizable: "false",
            Title: "Info"
            });

     })

    </SCRIPT>

<A id=portfoliopic href="#"><IMG style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 102px; LEFT: 390px" border=0 src="iconplace.png"></A>

<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=portfolio title=Portfolio>Portfolio pics</DIV>

  <SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

  $("#portfoliopic").click(function() {

        $("portfolio").dialog({
            autoOpen:"false", 
            stack:"true",
            height: "600",
            width: "700",
            resizable: "false"
            });

     })

    </SCRIPT>


</BODY></HTML>
```

On a side note, this doesn't work in Firefox or Safari, but works in Google Chrome and IE. Any speculation on that would be helpful as well.

Comment: you need to clean your code up. all of your id's and titles are missing quotations., the same with the 'language' and 'type' attributes. all need to be encased in ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$("portfolio").dialog({` to `$("#portfolio").dialog({`. That should get the second dialog box to work.

And I re-iterate @Ohgodwhy's suggestion to clean up your code.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now. Derp. Thank you very much. The code editor I use removes the quotations when I place them.